# If condition within Pipe with Select-Object and Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I want to execute a Select-Object and where Object command within a pipe under the if condition. I have searched for this case, but can find only the case with for-each-object and a specific value of a cell of the csv.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
[bool] $existdate = 1
[bool] $existstock = 1 

import-csv 'C:\temp\in.csv' | 
if (!$existdate) {Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty  'deliverydate1', 'deliverydate2' } | 
#[...some more code]
if ($existstock) {where-Object {[decimal]$_.stock_supplier -le 30} | where-Object stock_supplier -NotLike '0' | where stock_supplier -NotLike '' } else {where stock_supplier -Like 'low stock' } |
export-csv 'C:\temp\out.csv'
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are wanting the first `if (!$existdate) {<code>}` to do?  Is it something along the lines of remove delivery dates from objects on pipeline if `$existdate` is false?

Comment: Darin, i have to remove two columns (deliverydate 1 and 2)  from the csv  if existdate is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use entire language statements such as `if` directly in a pipeline.

Instead, you must build the conditional logic into [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) or [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) calls, or, if feasible, conditionally construct command arguments ahead of time.

Applied to your case:

```bash
[bool] $existdate = $true
[bool] $existstock = $true

# Determine what properties to exclude ahead of time, depending 
# on the value of $existdate
$excludedProperties =
  if ($existdate) { @() } else { 'deliverydate1', 'deliverydate2' }

Import-Csv 'C:\temp\in.csv' | 
  Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty $excludedProperties |
  Where-Object {
    # Apply the conditional logic to each input object ($_)
    if ($existstock) { 
      [decimal] $_.stock_supplier -le 30 -and $_.stock_supplier -NotLike '0' -and $_.stock_supplier -NotLike '' 
    }
    else { 
      $_.stock_supplier -Like 'low stock' 
    }
  }
  #[...some more code]
 |
  Export-Csv 'C:\temp\out.csv'
```

Comment: mklement0 thank you very, very much for your help. I will try and come back.

Comment: i fully understand it now. Thank you very much mklement0. It worked perfectly. Thank you, Alex